# Slide effect during setting the row/columnn position of element in a grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, grid, slide

I am changing the `row/column` position of certain elements in my application programmatically. I wanted to know if I can add any effect like `slide`, etc. during doing this changing thing. If yes, then how? The switching doesn't look good as so need some kind of `slider` effect.

Thank You.

Comment: `I am changing the row/column position of certain elements in my application programmatically` - I don't know what you're trying to do but one does not usually do that. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to implement it in WPF. If you can't post images here, try `imgur.com`.

Comment: I want to manage screen space in my application. So, using it.
Well, I have a menu of tiles at the top and an image below it. So, when I hover over a tile, the tile expands and displays menu options. Hence, I have to decrease the image size accordingly(so I place it in a row below). But this transition is quite quick. I need to make it smooth, like a slide effect.
Hope you understood what I am trying to do!